# Access MovieClip within a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flash-cs5

I have a MovieClip called Tile, which has its own class. I have the below code in a for loop, which creates a grid.

```
var tile:MovieClip = new Tile();
tile.gotoAndStop(Floor1[i][u]+1);
tile.x = ((u-i)*tileh)+365;
tile.y = ((u+i)*tileh/2)+70;
addChild(tile);

tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseover);
```

Now, there's another moveiclip in Tile called Outline. It is not a class. What I want to do is to have the Outline movieclip go to a frame when I roll over the tile variable with my mouse.

Below is the function for the mouse event. I have tried event.currentTarget.Outline.gotoAndStop(3) but it doesn't seem to work. I get a reference error #1069: Property Outline not found on Tile and there is no default value.

```
function mouseover(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            event.currentTarget.Outline.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Outline` (all variables should be lower case, camel case by the way. Capital implies it is a class name) a public variable? You should declare Outline in global scope as follows:

```
package com.blah.blah
{
    public class Tile extends DisplayObjectContainer {

        public var outline:DisplayObject;

        public function Tile() {
            // instantiate outline here
        }
    }
}
```

Basic explanation of access modifiers:

- **Public**: Can be accessed from any class
- **Private**: Can be accessed from only the class it is declared in
- **Internal**: Can be accessed only by classes in the same package
- **Static**: Only one instance exists, can only be accessed through class
  scope (Class.function())
- **Protected**: Only classes that extend that class can access that object
- **Final**: Children cannot override the function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Apocalyptic0n3!

First, I changed my MovieClip Outline to have a class. Am I putting public var outline in the Tile class, or in my Main class? I forget to mention that the code I posted above is all in the Main.

Comment: " another moveiclip in Tile called Outline. It is not a class" So you would do it in Tile. And access it in that event listener as `( e.currentTarget as Tile ).Outline`